# Rails ActionController::ParameterMissing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update the status field on a form independently of the form itself. In other words, the user can change the status via a pop up. Once they hit submit, the window with the form closes. I have a similar situation that works but can't duplicate it here.

I am calling the popup with.

```
   <%= link_to( '<button>Change the status</button>'.html_safe,
                           "/complaints/edit_status",
                           'data-popup' => true,
                           remote: true,
                           :class => "button_class",
                           :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'change the status', 'height=500, width=500');
                                         return false;"
                  ) %><br>
```

my applicable routes are

```
get 'complaints/edit_status' => 'complaints#edit_status'
  post 'complaints/edit_status' => 'complaints#edit_status'
```

The edit_status method in my controller is

```
  def edit_status
  @complaint = Complaint.find($current_record_id)
   respond_to do |format|
   if @complaint.update_attributes(complaint_params)
         format.html { render :text => '<script type="text/javascript">
                                         alert("The status was updated");
                                          window.close();
                                          </script>' }
   else                                                                         # otherwise show a standard message
        format.html { render :text => '<script type="text/javascript">
                                         alert(" There was an error in saving");
                                          window.close();
                                         </script>'
        }
   end
     end
  end
```

my edit_status.html.erb is simply `<%= render 'form_for_status' %>`

My complaints form is

```
<%= form_for @complaint, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <% if @complaint.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@complaint.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this complaint from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @complaint.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
          <div class="field" id="refresh_status">
            <%= f.label :status %><br>
            <%= f.select :status, options_for_status, :prompt => 'Select One' %>
          </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The error I am getting is

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ComplaintsController#edit_status
param is missing or the value is empty: complaint

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:252:in `complaint_params'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:16:in `block in edit_status'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:14:in `edit_status'
```

If I remark out the respond_to block, then the form works but it doesn't close when submitted.

If I leave the respond_to in (without the `<% @complaint.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>` then the form simply closes.

If I have the respond_to and `<% @complaint.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>` then I get the error indicated.

My log shows

```
Started GET "/complaints/edit_status" for ::1 at 2016-03-11 11:25:54 -0500
Processing by ComplaintsController#edit_status as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [ic].[users].* FROM [ic].[users] WHERE [ic].[users].[id] = @0  ORDER BY [ic].[users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mComplaint Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mEXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [ic].[complaints].* FROM [ic].[complaints] WHERE [ic].[complaints].[id] = @0  ORDER BY [ic].[complaints].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: complaint):
  app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:252:in `complaint_params'
  app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:16:in `block in edit_status'
  app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:14:in `edit_status'
```

Comment: what does inspect  params get you?

Comment: @Davinj `inspect params {"controller"=>"complaints", "action"=>"edit_status"}`   I think I see what you mean, the complaint parameter is not there.